# I am tring to insert data in gridview but it is not showing any error where as data is also in inserting

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am tring to insert data in gridview but it is not showing any error where as data is also in inserting.

My code:

```
protected void InsertData1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlserver"].ConnectionString);
            TextBox t1 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox2");
            TextBox t2 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox4");
            TextBox t3 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox6");
            TextBox t4 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox8");
            TextBox t5 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox10");
            TextBox t6 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox12");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblHelpDesk (Name,Purpose,ContactNo,AlternativeNo,Email,Address) values(@Name,@Purpose,@ContactNo,@AlternativeNo,@Email,@Address)", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", t1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", t2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", t3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlternativeNo", t4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", t5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", t6.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Comment: output the cmd query so you try and run that directly to help debug the problem

Comment: Put `throw ex` inside `catch (Exception ex)` and see what error returned by current query state.

Comment: Response.Redirect with true parameter ends the execution of the current page. You have it inside your loop so at max one record will be added

Comment: Why you are doing for loop even if you are redirecting every time.

Comment: let just ignore the fact we could drop the whole table with this code...

Comment: dont know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void InsertData1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 try
  {
    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        con = new  SqlConnection    
         (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlserver"].ConnectionString);



        TextBox t1 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox2");
        TextBox t2 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox4");
        TextBox t3 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox6");
        TextBox t4 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox8");
        TextBox t5 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox10");
        TextBox t6 = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox12");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblHelpDesk 
        (Name,Purpose,ContactNo,AlternativeNo,Email,Address) 
        values(@Name,@Purpose,@ContactNo,@AlternativeNo,@Email,@Address)", 
         con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", t1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", t2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", t3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlternativeNo", t4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", t5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", t6.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
  Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
 }
catch (Exception ex)
 { }
```

}